# Trouble to display a recordset

Tags: vba, recordset

```
Public Function `RecordsetSybase(sqlstr As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    If TestSybaseConnection() = False Then
        setLogin
    End If

    Dim commandObject As ADODB.Command
    Set commandObject = New ADODB.Command
    Dim data As New ADODB.Recordset
    With commandObject
        .CommandText = sqlstr
        .ActiveConnection = SybaseConnection(getUID, getPASS)
        .CommandTimeout = 350
    End With

    data.Open commandObject.CommandText, commandObject.ActiveConnection

    'Do Until data.EOF = True
    'MsgBox data(0)
    'data.MoveNext
    'Loop

    commandObject.ActiveConnection.Close

    Set RecordsetSybase = data
    Set commandObject = Nothing

End Function

Sub classific()

    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

   'Query
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT name_short_orig, cl_rating " & _
             "FROM pbsm_hist.dbo.pbsm_auths_hist_adjusted " & _
             "WHERE name_short_orig IS NOT Null " & _
             "AND cl_rating NOT IN ('F+','F','Z') "

    Set rs = RecordsetSybase(strSQL)
    MsgBox rs  
End Sub
```

I can display the recordset in the function (see comments).
But I cannot do it in the sub, I get the following error message:

> Run-time error '13':
>   Type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely bypassing the command object, currently its just sitting there storing the command text and connection.

To actually [use the command object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675065(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
set data = commandObject.execute()
```

As for the error, `MsgBox rs` is not valid - what would you expect to see as the string representation of the `rs` object?

If you wanted the 1st value:

```
if not rs.eof then msgbox rs.collect(0)
```